# How to set log level in chronos

Tags: java, docker, scala, docker-compose, mesos

I'm trying to change the `loglevel` in chronos from the default `INFO` to `TRACE`. I have gone through the docs and they seem to be outdated as per [this](https://github.com/mesos/chronos/issues/852) issue.

I have done a local setup using docker but to no avail

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  zk1:
    image: zookeeper
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zk1:2888:3888

  chronos:
    image: docker.io/mesosphere/chronos:chronos-2.5.1-0.1.20171211074431.ubuntu1404-mesos-1.3.1
    command: /usr/bin/chronos run_jar --http_port 4400 --master zk://zk1:2181/mesos --zk_hosts zk://zk1:2181/mesos
    ports:
      - "4400:4400"
    environment:
      "JVM_OPTS": "-Dlogback.configurationFile=/tmp/logback.xml"
    volumes:
      - ./logback.xml:/tmp/logback.xml
    depends_on:
      - zk1
```

lockback.xml

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>Custom - %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `-Dlogback.configurationFile` is not a `JVM_OPTS`

Answer (score 0):

Use `JAVA_OPTS` instead of `JVM_OPTS`

---

`/usr/bin/chronos` is a bash wrapper that runs Java and attached binary when no jar is provided. It setups all Java options and accepts configurations only with `JAVA_OPTS`. If noting provided then only `-Xmx512m` is set.